# Representations of $\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Q})$

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, representation-theory

Let's say that as a representation theorist I am naively interested in representations of $G(\mathbb{Q})$, where $G$ is an algebraic group defined over $\mathbb{Q}$. For the purposes of this question, we can assume $G$ is split reductive or even $\text{GL}_2$. A lot is known about representations of $G(\mathbb{A}_{\mathbb{Q}})$ because of the connection with Galois representations, but when I read about that subject people usually consider $G(\mathbb{Q})$-invariant functions and then not much is said about the latter group.

For $G = \text{GL}_1$, the structure of $G(\mathbb{Q}) = \mathbb{Q}^{\times}$ is given explicitly by the fundamental theorem of arithmetic and its characters are manifest. But I don't know much about the abstract group $\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Q})$ or its representation theory. What can be said here?

**Edit:** As Qiaochu points out, even for $\mathbb{Q}^{\times}$ indecomposable representations need not be irreducible (after all, this group is almost free abelian), and classifying infinite-dimensional representations seems pretty hopeless. However, I think my question is still interesting if we only ask for a classification of indecomposable finite-dimensional representations: certainly for $\mathbb{Q}^{\times}$ this has some content.

Comment: My guess is very little. It's hard enough to say things about finitely generated groups...

Comment: By the way, I don't think it's so obvious what the representation theory of $\mathbb{Q}^{\times}$ is already. You are correct that its one-dimensional representations are obvious, but an infinite abelian group can have indecomposable representations...

Comment: Fair enough, but $\mathbb{Q}^{\times}$ is free abelian on the primes times the $2$-group, so a representation just consists of a countable family of operators, one for each prime, together with an involution. Of course $\text{GL}_2(\mathbb{Q})$ is harder because it is nonabelian, but I don't see why it being infinitely presented is so bad.

Comment: Right, so that tells you what the finite-dimensional representations look like, but I don't even know what the infinite-dimensional representations of $\mathbb{Z}$ look like. Anyway, already the representation theory of a finitely generated group like $F_2$ is intractable, so I don't see a reason to expect anything good from an infinitely generated group.

Comment: Oh, that's a valid point: I wouldn't expect anything nice for arbitrary infinite-dimensional representations either. Let's just restrict to finite-dimensional representations then. Already answering this question for $\text{GL}_1$ involves the fundamental theorem of arithmetic and the Jordan normal form, both of which are elementary but interesting.